# How to install FreeFileSync in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: software-installation, 16.10

I've extracted the files but now what do I do?

[image]

Comment: where did you download this from please?

Comment: http://www.freefilesync.org/

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Run these commands:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/FreeFileSync
   ./FreeFileSync              #I haven't used this program, so I don't know if it requires arguments or not
   ```

**Note:**

If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, and you are trying to run a 32-bit compiled program, you will need to install the 32-bit libraries.

**EDIT:**

To fix the errors you are getting, try running:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```

And then try step #2 again.

Comment: :~/Downloads/FreeFileSync$ ./FreeFileSync
./FreeFileSync: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ./FreeFileSync)
./FreeFileSync: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./FreeFileSync)
./FreeFileSync: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./FreeFileSync)

Comment: What a mess! I can't seem to format it. Anyway, I guess I need to install the missing dependencies - if possible. Or retreat to 14.04 for a bit longer... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've made a mistake... I should start again and this question should be deleted - I've been using Ubuntu since Dapper and suddenly, with Ubuntu 16, it is like I have never used it before. I rely on FreeFileSync daily so I will have to wait and hope for someone to make it work or find an alternative.

Comment: @user104140 I suggest that you do not delete this question.

Comment: I can't delete the question so I have flagged it for a moderator to delete. The response from the terminal on entering your suggestion "./FreeFileSync" is not want I reported above but "error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0". Its given me a headache. The device fails to connect with wifi, fails to suspend... and in 14 it works perfectly. I'm done with it.

Answer (score 0):

The official PPA is not supported but the program, current version 8.7, does support 16.04 and 16.10. You can manually install just by extracting the `*.tar.gz` file into any folder.  FreeFileSync is an executable binary and needs no install.

Follow these instructions https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-freefilesync-ubuntu-16-04  Make sure you scroll down the page for the manual download and install instructions.  There is a step by step to create a launcher icon on the launcher bar.

I run 16.04.01 LTS and was able to move the folder and create a launcher using the instructions on that page.

FreeFileSync is an executable binary there is no installation required but you should place the FreeFileSync folder into a more appropriate folder such as `/opt/FreeFileSync` as explained on the page from the link above.